# Representations of Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

It's not at all obvious to me why a connected and simply connected Lie group has only single valued linear irreducible representations. This would come as a particular case to a more general statement: a connected n-fold connected Lie group has at most n-valued linear irreducible representations.

Can one prove this general statement mixing somehow the homotopy group and representation morphism? I haven't seen a proof for this, but the result is taken for granted in the physicists' community.

Thanks,
BR,
Daniel

Comment: The physics related part comes from the (otherwise excellent) book of Fonda and Ghirardi (1970) - section 3.2.5 page 156. There are a bunch of  unsubstantiated claims which I extracted for my question.

Comment: It is unclear to me what "single valued linear irreducible representation" means. Presumably, this has to do with the fundamental group. For simply connected Lie groups this is trivial, whereas for $n$-connected Lie groups, it has order $n$.

Comment: IIRC, there's an isomorphism between the Lie group L and its universal cover factored by the fundamental group of L: $L \simeq \frac{\tilde{L}}{\pi(L)} $. How could I use this in representation theory?

Comment: Is it true that the fundamental group is the center of $\tilde{L}$?

Comment: I have never heard of either of the terms "$n$-fold connected" or "$n$-valued representation," but my guess is that your question is about projective representations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) and when they can be lifted to actual representations. Is that right?

Comment: @David Hill. No, by my understanding of Pontrjagin, I don't think so.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan. No, I'm not hinting at Bargmann's work. n-fold connected is my own phrasing of multiple connected or n-connected. One says that an a group representation is n-valued, if one group element is represented by n different linear operators. Think about SO(3). It's said to have double-valued unitary linear representations (so-called spinor ones).

Comment: That really sounds to me like you're talking about projective representations. Do the linear operators you're talking about differ by a scalar multiple?

Comment: @DavidHill Not in general: suppose, for example,  the group is Abelian e.g., $G= \mathbb R$, in which case the center is the whole group. But the kernel of a covering map $\pi: \tilde G \rightarrow G$  is always in the center - sketch of a proof: say  $k$ in the kernel, and $g\in \tilde G$. Consider a path $\gamma(t)$ (in $\tilde G$), with $\gamma(0) = \tilde e$, and $\gamma(1) = g$. (continued)

Comment: @DavidHill (continued) Then $ \pi (\gamma(t) k \gamma (t)^{-1})= e$. On the other hand, restricted to any covering neighborhood of $e$, $\pi$ is by definition a homeomorphism - so $\gamma(t) k \gamma(t)^{-1}$  is constant, and so $gkg^{-1}=k$.
On the other hand, if $G$ is semi-simple, you are basically right: the center of $\tilde G$ is the fundamental group of the adjoint form of $\tilde G$.

Comment: @DanielC - no expert am I - but let me say I too am confused by what you are asking. It is true that if $G$ is simply connected (and connected - but assume that always the case for lie groups), that any finite dimensional representation of its lie algebra lifts - in your (counter)-example ${\rm SO}_3(\mathbb R)$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/2$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @DanielC - I should have added: so there will be representations of its universal cover which do not descend to ${\rm SO_3} ( \mathbb R)$.

Comment: Alright, one more time. I'm not talking about projective representations, but about vector ones. So my question is: I want to represent a connected, simply connected Lie group $ \tilde{G} $ on a vector space V. The representation morphism is $ \rho : G \mapsto \mathbb{Aut} (V) $.

Comment: [continued] One claims that this morphism is single-valued, i.e. one group element is mapped to one operator only. If you now put G which is double connected, there's no way you can build "true" vector representations which all of them are single-valued. SO(3)+SU(2) provide the example. I want a proof of the general case.

Comment: Sorry for seeming/being dense. The thing is, your (physicist's?) language is from, our point of view, a bit odd: a (Lie group) morphism $G \to H$ (e.g., $H$ a general linear group) is always single-valued - in fact, one basically no longer says 'multi-valued function' - I  think! - at all...  We would say that a (single-valued, always) morphism $\phi:\tilde G \to H$, where $\tilde G$ is the universal cover of $G$, descends to a morphism to $G$, precisely when the kernel of $\phi$ (i.e., $\phi^{-1}(1)$) contains the fundamental group of $G$. (cont.)

Comment: (cont) Stated in this way, this is almost a tautology. Viewed from $G$, the number of 'operators' (elements in $H$) depend on how the fundamental group intersects with the kernel of $\phi$. Is this what you have in mind? But, if $G$ is simply connected, for any Lie algebra homomorphism $f$ between the corresponding Lie algebras,  there is a Lie group morphism (single-valued!) $\phi:G \to H$ such that $d\phi = f$. Are you looking for a proof of this? -n.b. I deleted the 1st version of these 2 comments because of a terrible 'typo'.

Comment: (cont.) To match up more explicitly with the phrasing in your question:  I don't think that it makes sense to ask why a s.c. group 'only' has single valued representations as it comes down to asking why  there is no (non-trivial) cover of the s.c. group - by definition, there is none.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I found a worded proof by Cartan in his book on spinors. I will post this below under answers

Answer (score 1):

I want to present Elie Cartan's argument about representations of simply connected Lie groups:

[...] *it is seen that the space of the unimodular unitary group is a manifold in which
each point is defined by four real numbers a1, a2, b1, b2 for which the sum of
squares equals 1; i.e., it is a spherical space of three dimensions (the hyper-
sphere of unit radius in Euclidean space of four dimensions). This space is
simply connected in the sense that all closed contours can be reduced to
a point by continuous deformation. This can easily be seen by considering
the inverse of the hypersphere in four dimensions with respect to a point of
itself (stereographic projection); this inverse is a three-dimensional Euclidean
space (including the point at infinity). Then it can be shown that if the  unimodular group had a multi-valued representation, on following the continuous
variation of the representing matrix as the point in group space describes a
suitable closed contour starting and finishing at some origin, the matrix
would start as the unit matrix and finish as a different matrix. On continuously
deforming the contour the final matrix will remain the same. But the contour
can be deformed so as to reduce to one point—the origin. This gives a

contradiction.[...]*